# "Answer your own question" toggle stops working after ticking the checkbox consecutively

Tags: bug, answers, user-interface, self-answer

In some case, the "Answer your own question" is unchecked, but the answer box is present. This happens when clicking a few times on "Answer your own question".

[image: screenshot of answer box present while checkbox unticked]

Demo:

[image: gif animation of the bug in progress]

I didn't intend to stress test the system, I just have a sensitive dwell clicker.

Comment: Normal user will never just keep clicking the checkbox, that happens only for people who "stress test" the system, so don't think it's really a bug.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I didn't intend to stress test the system, I just have a sensitive dwell clicker.

Comment: So better mention it, sorry. What I mean it that this isn't ordinary workflow of a user, so still a rare edge case.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I once had a mouse that would sometimes register multiple clicks when I would click only once.